# Jenkins publish over ssh success to connect the server but failed put file

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssh, amazon-web-services, jenkins

I have a problem that when I do build to my job, its cannot put my file on the server directory in console output i get the message  "ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Permission denied]"

i have the following log output:

```
SSH: Connecting from host [rp_ci]
SSH: Connecting with configuration [web-dev] ...
SSH: Creating session: username [ubuntu], hostname [xx.xx.xx.xxx], port [22]
SSH: Connecting session ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: Opening SFTP channel ...
SSH: SFTP channel open
SSH: Connecting SFTP channel ...
SSH: Connected
SSH: Remote root is not absolute, getting absolute directory from PWD
SSH: cd [/home/ubuntu]
SSH: OK
SSH: cd [deploy/]
SSH: OK
SSH: put [dev-xx-xx.tgz]
SSH: Disconnecting configuration [web-dev] ...
ERROR: Exception when publishing, exception message [Permission denied]
Build step 'Send build artifacts over SSH' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

For the target server Im using ubuntu server on AWS EC2 using nginx.

Someone know how to fix that's issue? I not found any clue for it around the web.
Thanks!

Comment: What happens if you run the script manually as the Jenkins user? Any reason you're not using SCP instead of SFTP?

Comment: it is work in all my other servers, while Im using SCP I prompt an error:" Host key verification failed."

Answer (score 1):

Permission denied when `put dev-xx-xx.tgz`. So check the file's permission setup: `/home/Ubuntu/deploy/dev-xx-xx.tgz`

Comment: You need to elaborate some more on what the problem is in order to turn this into a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

After looking at the [plugin source code,](https://github.com/jenkinsci/publish-over-ssh-plugin) it appears that it defaults to using a relative path if no "*Remote Directory*" is set in your  ssh server configuration.

Go to *Manage Jenkins*/*Confgiure System* and under the plugin settings for publish over ssh, set **Remote Directory** to **"/"**